# Storing usersettings in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

I develop a SharePoint Farm Solution.

I want to save the settings (like sorting of each grid) for each User. 
Is there a possible best practise to do this?

Or is there the only way to use a profile manager for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have settings for one web only, you can create a hidden list within the web and store user information there. If you index your "user" column the access with a CAML query should be really fast.

If it is not a must have, that these information are really persistent for each user no matter which device, you can save it in a cookie.

Comment: Hi thx for your reply. I thought about it, but i don't know the performance of this usage. But I don't thought about indexing the elements. But there is a limitation of the threshold items or is that only for the frontend display?

Comment: The 5000 item limit is not a hard limit on lists, it is just a "view" limit. The real limit is 30,000,000 (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#ListLibrary)